# Syntax error when switching basemaps using Esri Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet

I'm kind of new at using Leaflet and have a question for an issue that keeps popping up.

I'm using the code from the example here:

https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/switching-basemaps.html

Everything works fine using this code, however I want only the Streets and Imagery options in my drop-down with Streets as default.  Therefore I have:

```
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="basemaps-wrapper">
        <select name="basemaps" id="basemaps" onchange="changeBasemap(basemaps)">
            <option value="Streets">Streets</option>
            <option value="Imagery">Imagery</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map', { zoomControl: false });
    map.setView([50, -25], 4)
    //var map = L.map('map').setView([50, -25], 4);
    map.zoomControl = false;
    var layer = L.esri.basemapLayer('Streets').addTo(map);
    var layerLabels;

    L.control.zoom({
        position: 'topright'
    }).addTo(map);

    function setBasemap(basemap) {
        if (layer) {
            map.removeLayer(layer);
        }

        layer = L.esri.basemapLayer(basemap);

        map.addLayer(layer);

        if (layerLabels) {
            map.removeLayer(layerLabels);
        }

        if (basemap === 'ShadedRelief'
         || basemap === 'Oceans'
         || basemap === 'Gray'
         || basemap === 'DarkGray'
         || basemap === 'Imagery'
         || basemap === 'Terrain'
       ) {
            layerLabels = L.esri.basemapLayer(basemap + 'Labels');
            map.addLayer(layerLabels);
        }
    }

    function changeBasemap(basemaps) {
        var basemap = basemaps.value;
        setBasemap(basemap);
    }
</script>
```

When I load the page like this, I receive the following error:

`JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 66683 in https://static.arcgis.com/attribution/World_Street_Map?callback=window._EsriLeafletCallbacks.c0&f=json\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error`

Any thoughts?  I can simply continue and the page loads normally, but why is this happening?

Using Visual Studio and IE11.

Comment: is there error only displayed in IE11? i can't reproduce on my machine http://jsbin.com/gakolek/edit?html,output

Comment: It appears to have been a caching problem.  Ctrl + F5 and all seems to work well.  Thanks.